# How can I paste text from the system's xopy-paSTE buffer (for instance, from a web browser under Linux) into Emacs Evil-mode?

Tags: copy-paste

I was sure this question had already been asked, but I couldn't find it on this SE.

I would like to paste text from Chrome's view page source, on Cinnamon on Linux Mint, into an Emacs window.

The menu has paste options, but they do not seem to be sensitive to material on the system's paste buffer.

How can I access the system's paste buffer?

Comment: I think `"+p`, same as in Vim. `"*p` for the primary selection (mouse highlight without an explicit copy command).

Comment: The question isn't very clear, to me. What have you tried? What are your values of `select-active-regions`, `select-enable-clipboard` and `select-enable-primary`? Have you consulted the Emacs manual, nodes [Primary Selection](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Primary-Selection.html) and [Clipboard](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Clipboard.html)?